# Filter like %[A-Za-z]% in databricks

Tags: apache-spark, t-sql, databricks, spark-notebook

I am trying to use `table.column LIKE '%[A-Za-z]%` in Databricks notebook, but it returns no value.

It worked in SQL server, but it seems it's not working in Pysql.

Does anyone know what's the alternative in Databricks?

Comment: Sorry I am quite new to databricks. I don't think I created df, but I queried directly againt tables directly.

Comment: Sorry, but the table would show anything regarding what I asked because I am not selecting this column, but just filtering it.

Answer (score 2):

The [LIKE function](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/index.html#like) has a limited functionality, so you need to use [rlike](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/index.html#rlike) instead:

```
select * .... where column rlike '.*[A-Za-z].*'
```

Update: real example:

```py
%python
df = spark.createDataFrame([{'id': 1, 's':'12323'}, {'id': 1, 's':'123T23'}], 
  schema='id int, s string')
df.createOrReplaceTempView("rlike_test")
```

and query:

```sql
%sql
select * from rlike_test where s rlike '.*[A-Za-z].*'
```

here is result of execution:

[image]

Comment: Hi Alex, thank you so much. Is there any document I can have a look? I struggled to find one.

Comment: What do you mean? Examples are in the linked documentation

Comment: Hm. I just tried it, but it seems it doesn't work. By the way, I am on Databricks. I don't know if this makes any difference.